# Finding Xpath Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have the following element:

```
<div class="PickList visible" 
 widgetid="Palette" id="Palette">
 <span class="stuff">
 <span class="stuff"><span class="lbl">A-B</span><span class="no">1111</span> 
 </span>
 <span class="stuffSelect"><span class="lblSelect">C</span><span 
  class="plu">2222</span></span>
```

The xpath that I am using is:

```
Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="Palette"]//span//span[2]//span[contains(text(),'C')]"));
```

It's still not able to pickup the letter 'C'.

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned below that the span with class="lblSelect" will not be unique.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish?  are you trying to specifically find the span containing "C"?  Or are you trying to find the span(s) with class="stuffSelect" inside the div @id="Palette"?

Comment: I agree with @BreaksSoftware.  Your requirements are not clear at all, and apparently none of the four offered solutions work?  The double-slashes scattered throughout your xpath and some of the supplied answers don't make much sense, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath you are using is incorrect. I am providing you with the correct xpath or you can directly fetch it using the className as well.

**Updated xpath as per the discussion:**

```
WebElement selectedCharacter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Palette']//span[@class='lblSelect']"));
selectedCharacter.getText();
```

**By using className:**

```
WebElement selectedCharacter = driver.findElement(By.className("lblSelect"));
selectedCharacter.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the thing is I can't use lblSelect because it's not unique, in future there can be more lblSelect.

Comment: Okk then you can append the id along with the classname in the xpath. I am editing my answer, please try that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below xpath to track from div.

```
driver.findElement("//*[@id='Palette']/span[2][@class='stuffSelect']/span[1][contains(text(), 'C')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Xpath.It will print you 'C'

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='Palette']//span[1]//span[2]/span)[1]")).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath. Consider the class `visible` in your xpath or css. As this denotes that this div might be not visible sometimes. So always be sure to use the `visible` if you have it as part of the class.

**CSS**

```
div.PickList.visible span.lblSelect
```

**xpath**

```
//div[@class='PickList visible']//span[@class='lblSelect']
```